# Spring: Cannot resolve parameter names for constructor

Tags: java, spring, rest

When trying to invoke the REST endpoint of the following interface for a Spring @RestController:

```
public interface ComputationCallback
{
   @PostMapping("task")
   boolean startTask(
         @RequestParam(value = "taskId") UUID taskId
   );
}
```

I get this strange error message:

```
Cannot resolve parameter names for constructor public java.util.UUID(long,long)
```

The controller implementing the method looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class ComputationCallbackController implements ComputationCallback
{
   @Override public boolean startTask(UUID taskId)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I discovered that this error does not relate to the conversion of the UUID value. What was missing is the annotation on the method in the implementing class. The parameters in the interface do not seem to be discoverable. So changing the implementation to

```
@RestController
public class ComputationCallbackController implements ComputationCallback
{
   @Override public boolean startTask(@RequestParam(value = "taskId") UUID taskId)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

fixed the error.